# Are strongly close maps homotopic?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

While reading about various results related to density of smooth functions in the space of continuous functions with strong topology, I've got the impression that it is a general fact that for any continuous function $f:X\to Y$ between smooth manifolds, there is a strong neighbourhood $\mathcal U$ of $f$ which is contained in homotopy class of $f$, that is, for any $g\in\mathcal U$ there is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

It would also be a very nice result in any case, but I've yet to find the fact spelled out in clear terms, neither did I find a proof.

I would appreciate a hint or a reference to literature.

Notes:

1. This question is closely related (pardon the pun) to the question [Are close maps homotopic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185396/are-close-maps-homotopic), but this is different in that I allow arbitrary strong neighbourhoods (and the counterexamples listed there do not work in this more general context).
2. It is also related to a question of mine: [Are locally homotopic functions homotopic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264752/are-locally-homotopic-functions-homotopic) – I believe that we can show that there is a strong neighbourhood of $f$ which is contained in „local homotopy class” in the sense explained in the question, using local convex structure of $Y$.
3. A different idea of a proof would be showing that any continuous function has a contractible neighbourhood in the space of continuous functions by some abstract argument, but I'm not sure about the technical details of that.

Edit: I think I've managed to prove the fact, but the proof is somewhat long and I'm rather tired right now, so I won't write it down right now. If someone is really curious I probably might give a sketch. In any case, a reference would probably be the best answer, unless someone knows a simple proof of this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for a reference, I give this

https://www.sanzytorres.es/listado.php?origen=buscador&busqueda=Topolog%EDa+Diferencial&buscar2.x=53&buscar2.y=8

What can be seen there is (Prop. III.7.1):

Let $X\subset{\mathbb R}^m$ any locally closed ($\equiv$ locally compact) set and $Y\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ a smooth manifold possibly with boundary. Then homotopy (resp. proper homotopy) classes $[X,Y]$ are open in the strong topology.

As for the proof, since I don't know yours, I just say it uses a continuous retraction from a "tubular" neighborhood of $Y\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ onto $Y$. The boundary gives some trouble for differentiable purposes, but not here.